# 2 simple SQL queries within PHP throwing errors

Tags: php, mysql

Still relatively new to PHP so I might be making some easy mistakes here.

The code below throws warnings:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/unn_w14017307/public_html/Assignment3/JakeUploads/11March/logonProcess.php on line 87

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/unn_w14017307/public_html/Assignment3/JakeUploads/11March/logonProcess.php on line 88

Warning: mysqli_stmt_store_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/unn_w14017307/public_html/Assignment3/JakeUploads/11March/logonProcess.php on line 89

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/unn_w14017307/public_html/Assignment3/JakeUploads/11March/logonProcess.php on line 90
```

I assume this has something to do with the first query that I execute, as the first one works fine and then the second throws these errors.

Isn't a connection problem as the $conn works fine for the first query.

Here's the code:

```
 <?php
        $username = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'username') ? $_POST['username']: null;
        $password  = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'password') ? $_POST['password']: null;

        include 'database_conn.php';    // make db connection

        /* Query the users database table to get the password hash for the username entered by the user in the logon form */

        $sql = "SELECT password FROM Users WHERE username = ?";
        $typeSql = "SELECT type FROM Users WHERE username = $username";

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);    // prepare the sql statement

        /* Bind the $username entered by the user to the prepared statement. Note the “s” part indicates the data type used – in this case a string */

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);     

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // execute the query
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt); //store result so second query can be used
        /* Get the password hash from the query results for the given username and store it in the variable indicated */

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $returnedPass);

        /* Check if a record was returned by the query. If yes, then there was a username matching what was entered in the logon form and we can now test to see if the password entered in the logon form is the same as the stored (correct) one in the database. */

        if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            if($password === $returnedPass)
            {
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $typeSql);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $accountType);


                $_SESSION['uName'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
                $_SESSION['type'] = $type;

                echo "<p>Password valid</p>";
                echo "<p>Username: $username</p>";
                echo "<p>Account type: $type</p>";


            }
            else
            {
                echo "<p>Password invalid</p>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<p>Sorry we don't seem to have that username.</p>";
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: sidenote: why are you using two separate queries? You can do this in one.

Comment: check for the real error(s) with `mysqli_error($conn)` against the queries.

Comment: How would I do this in one query? I wasn't sure how to separate the password and type results from the query into separate variables using mysqli_stmt_bind_result

Comment: you select both columns, and bind on the username and bind the result on the password. However, you need to hash your passwords. Using plain text is unsafe. You're querying too hard ;-)

Comment: The encryption comes later. I just want to get this working first. But then how do I use the type column that I retrieved?

Comment: same principle.

Comment: so assuming I do `SELECT password, type FROM Users ...` etc 
Can I then do `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $returnedPass, $accountType); `since both the password and the type will be returned?

Comment: you could do that, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is that mysqli can only bind parameters to a `?`.

```
$sql = "SELECT password FROM Users WHERE username = ?";
$typeSql = "SELECT type FROM Users WHERE username = ?";
```

However, you should be preparing your statements only **once**:

```
if(! $typestmt =  mysqli_prepare($conn, $typeSql)){
  die('error in sql syntax');
}

if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
  if($password === $returnedPass)
  {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($typestmt, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($typestmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($typestmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($typestmt, $accountType);
  }
}
```

On a side note as [@Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740348/2-simple-sql-queries-within-php-throwing-errors/42740433#comment72598628_42740348) is saying storing plain text passwords is not safe.

Use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate a hash, store it as password and retrieve that value and use [`password_verify()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) with the hash stored into the database with the value the user provided to verify a login.

Another point is that you can combine the query to this:

```
SELECT password, type FROM Users WHERE username = ?
```

However for a secure login, I would do something like:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean I should only be preparing statements once? Can you expand a bit and show me what I'm doing wrong, just trying to understand this a bit further so I don't make the same mistake.

Comment: A statement is actually a query to fill in the blanks, you can rebind new updated values to it and execute it again.